# Состояние системы для приложений для Android

Tags: android

Как Android передает состояние системы приложению?  Например что экран заблокирован, или что она уходит в режим сна, можно ли ложные команды посылать приложению (подменить например)?

Answer (score 2):

При блокировании/засыпании система рассылает бродкаст (широковещательное извещение) `android.intent.action.screen_off`

При пробуждении `android.intent.action.screen_on`

Такой бродкаст ловится стандартным механизмом `BroadcastReceiver` - [документация здесь](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

Вручную (программно) сгенерировать  эти бродкасты невозможно (равно как и любой другой системный бродкаст) - при попытке технически сгенерировать такой бродкаст (через `sendBroadcast()`) будет выброшен экспешн:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.blah-blah

Comment: То есть способов отправить или перехватить и изменить бродкаст вообще никак нельзя?